# ADS8361 and F28335

Tags: microcontroller, adc

I'm trying to interface an [ADS8361](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/sbas230) with an [F28335](http://www.ti.com/product/tms320f28335). It looks like I have some timing issues when reading the data using the McBSP. I tried to follow the code and the schematics included in this [application note](http://www.ti.com/analog/docs/litabsmultiplefilelist.tsp?literatureNumber=slaa167&docCategoryId=1&familyId=2019&keyMatch=slaa167&tisearch=Search-EN-Everything) (for ADS8361 and F2812) but the differences between the F2812 and F28335 are baffling me. Apparently, my implementation mostly works, but sometimes the initial bit from the serial line is skipped; hence I suspect a timing issue, probably because of a wrong configuration of the McBSP. I'm using the hardware configuration illustrated in Figure 16 of the linked ADS8361 data sheet. Has anybody tried this configuration and is willing to share the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the differences between the F2812 and the F28335 are minimal: I just had to remove the code pertaining to FIFO to make it compile and run. Unfortunately there are a couple of mistakes in the sample code provided in the application note and in the ADC data sheet as well. In the code, the Frame Sync Generator is stopped after the DDR registers are read, but it's too late, so another frame sync is actually sent out, so an extra conversion is read from the ADC and queued in the McBSP. As per the data sheet, it states that the ADC sends four 0s at the end of the conversion but I've noticed that sometimes it send some 1s too; that's why I thought that I had timing issues.